# Updating a List<MyClass> collection based on a new List<MyClass> collection

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I need to update a List collection with a new List collection in a way that:

- the original List gets the new items from the new List
- the items on the original List which are not on the new List get deleted

Unfortunately, clearing the original List and rebuilding it from the new one is not an option because those already hold objects with important values/references I do not want to lose.

What I need to achieve can be summarized as follows:

[image]

I came up with 'some' solution which 'kind of' works, but I really don't like it and I am not sure how efficient this is...

```
class MyClass{
int someInt;
String someString;
int rowID; // DB reference, cannot lose it...
... 
}

public static List<MyClass> mergeMyClassLists(List<MyClass> origList, List<MyClass> newList){

    Integer index[]= new Integer[origList.size()];

    // Find the ones to remove from the old list
    int c=0;
    for(MyClass origMyClass:origList){       
       if(!hasMyClass(newList,origMyClass)) index[c] = origList.indexOf(origMyClass);
    c++;  
    }    

    // Then remove them
    for(int i:index){
    if(index[i]!=null)
        origList.remove(index[i]);
    }

    //Add new ones
    for(MyClass newMyClass:newList){        
        if(!hasMyClass(origList,newMyClass)) origList.add(newMyClass);      
    }           
return origList;
}

private static boolean hasMyClass(List<MyClass> myClassList, MyClass myClass){

    for(MyClass mc:myClassList){
        // Are they the same? based on my own criteria here
        if(mc.someInt == myClass.someInt && mc.someString.equals(myClass.someString)) return true; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Is there a better/standard way of doing this?** I get the feeling I might be over-complicating the situation...

Comment: `origList.retainAll(newList); newList.removeAll(origList); origList.addAll(newList);` maybe? Needs a good `MyClass.equals, hashcode`.

Comment: I want to match objects which may not be exactly the same (for example one does not have a value for rowID), but they match based on the condition I set.

Comment: Does `newList` have to be the same before and after the operation?

Comment: No, the new list will not be needed anymore..

Comment: Then I consider Joop's solution the best way. All elements in `origList` that are equal to any in `newList` are left untouched, while the rest are replaced. I wrote an answer based on the same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `equals` and `hashCode` in `MyClass` to fit your requirements for equality.

Here is an example:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if( !(o instanceof MyClass) ) return false;

    MyClass mc = (MyClass)o;
    if(this.someInt != mc.someInt)
        return false;
    return (this.someString == null)
            ? mc.someString == null
            : this.someString.equals(mc.someString);
}
public int hashCode() {
    int hashCode = someInt;
    if(someString != null)
        hashCode ^= someString.hashCode();
    return hashCode;
}
```

When you've overridden those, it's as simple as this:

```
origList.retainAll(newList);
newList.removeAll(origList);
origList.addAll(newList);
```

Comment: This works, but what is hashCode() for? It never seems to be reached when I debug my code.

Comment: @Croc Some collections compare hash codes when checking for equality, because comparing `int`s is faster than calling `equals`. For instance, `HashSet`s and `HashMap`s compare hash codes when checking for equality. For that reason,`hashCode` should always be overridden whenever you override `equals`. Equal objects must have the same hash code, but unequal objects don't need to have distinct hash codes, although it is preferred, for higher performance.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your requirement I guess that what matters most to you is only the elements of `newList` . So ,indirectly you want to remove all elements of `originalList` and add all elements of `newList` to the `originalList`. So instead of doing all these things I think you should simply write:

```
originalList = new ArrayList<MyClass>(newList);
```

Comment: If I remove all objects from the original List I will some of their field values. (e.g.: rowID) The objects in the new List might not be exactly the same, but are matched based on a simple condition. It is always the object in the original List I need to keep if they match.

Comment: See, What I see after reading your question and the `truth table` that you posted is that If the `originalList` records matched with `newList` then `Keep it` within `originalList` else just remove it. And add all new elements from `newList` to `originalList`. That's what exactly I am doing here. Or perhaps you need to clear out your question more.

Comment: Thanks for having an other look at this. Your last comment is correct, but it contradicts your answer... if I go with the code snippet in your answer I will lose all of the objects from the original List. Unless I am missing something...

Comment: If you are loosing all objects from `originalList` then on the another moment you are getting all elements from `newList` that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you **do not** want to **lose** the `originalList` then probably this code can help

```
List<String> orgList = new ArrayList<String>();
orgList.add("a");
orgList.add("b");

List<String> newList  = new ArrayList<String>();
newList.add("a");
newList.add("d");
newList.add("e");
newList.add("f");

List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> existingInBoth = new ArrayList<String>();
//Add item to result, if its present in newList BUT not in orgList
for(String s : newList) {
    if(!orgList.contains(s))
    result.add(s);
}
//Add the common items (this is inverse of removing the item which is there in orgList and not in newList)
for(String s : orgList) {
    if(newList.contains(s))
    existingInBoth.add(s);
}
result.addAll(existingInBoth);
System.out.println(result);
```

For this to work in your case, you need to make `MyClass` override `equals()` method of `java.lang.Object` class and define the **equality** of the objects. 
Reason being, the `contains(Object)` method essentially checks the **existance** of an object within the collection, by checking the **equality**(`ob1.equals(obj2)`) of the object, with all the elements in the collection.

The logic within the `equals()` method should be similar to the one which is written in `hasMyClass` method's `if` condition

Answer (score 0):

Put the items in NewList in a HashSet.  (You may need to use a custom IEqualityComparer in the HashSet depending on how you're instantiating the objects in NewList - given Object1 from OldList and Object2 from NewList, you can use the default constructor for HashSet if Object1 == Object2, but you'll need to create a custom IEqualityComparer if Object1 != Object2 and Object1.equals(Object2).)  Iterate though OldList - if NewHashSet.contains(object) then remove the object from NewHashSet, otherwise remove the object from OldList.  Next, iterate through NewHashSet, and add the remaining objects to OldList.  HashSet.contains runs in more-or-less constant time, so the entire merge method will run in linear time.